# Were certain enemies in TNG agents or puppets of Q?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

I'm going through *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, and I'm wondering whether some of the enemies were "puppets" or agents of Q. Namely:

- Armus - "Skin of Evil"
- Nagilum - "Where Silence has Lease"

Both seem interested in humanity (and other races) very much like how Q does.

Could these be "puppets" or agents of Q, or just the way the writing was done?

Comment: Q isn't really one for subtlety...

Comment: I suppose in Q-Who the Borg are agents of Q when Q decides to throw the enterprise in front of a Borg ship... It depends on what one considers an agent.

Comment: @ewanm89: Or are the Enterprise crew agents of Q against the Borg?

Comment: @Junuxx, yes that is also a possibility.

Comment: With Q, anything is possible. It's entirely possible that every member of the Enterprise-D except for Chief O'Brien was a Q-created/controlled hologram!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Armus**

Certainly not. His genesis is explicitly described in the episode and while it's possible that he had something to do with the Q (heck, anything is *possible* when Q is involved) it's vanishingly *unlikely*.

> **TROI:** *Abandoned. Who deserted you?*
>
> **ARMUS [OC]:** *Creatures whose beauty now dazzles all who see them. They would not exist without me.*
>
> **TROI:** *You were together?*
>
> **ARMUS [OC]:** *They perfected a means of bringing to the surface all that was evil and negative within. Erupting, spreading, connecting. In time it formed second skin, dank and vile*

Frankly, no part of that description matches what we know about the Q.

---

### **Nagilum**

*Almost* certainly not. Although he possesses many of the overt powers of the Q (the ability to manifest unreal objects, for example), his actions don't teach the crew anything. There's no "lesson learned", a common feature of all of the Q's interactions with humanity. He also seems rampantly (and needlessly) cruel, rather than possessing any of the vicious charm of Q. Frankly, murdering a junior crewman ***simply to make a point*** just isn't Q's style.

Compare

> **Nagilum:** *... Be that as it may -- as species, we have no common ground. You are too aggressive. Too hostile. Too militant.* - <sub><sup>Where Silence Has Lease</sup></sub>

with

> **Q:** *The Q became interested in you. Does no one here understand your incredible good fortune?* - <sub><sup>Hide and Q</sup></sub>

Comment: Only Q is dazzled by how beautiful Q is.

Comment: I wouldn't say that Nagilum killed the officer simply to make a point. From its point of view the entire encounter was an experiment. To it the death of an officer (or even half of the crew) was no different from a modern day scientist killing a number of mice via various means in order to see the affects on them.

Comment: @Xantec - Yes, but **if Nagilum was a Q-puppet**, then the crewman's death would have been to make a point. That's my point. He wasn't killed to make a point. It was pointless.

Comment: @Richard Pointless from our point of view, but I get what you're saying.